# How to paint pixels in Python according to their pixel value?

Tags: python, image, pixel

For example, i want to paint blue all pixels with the value of 90 in a grayscale image with python. How do i do that?

I have no idea on how to do It, i am pretty new to python

Comment: You may want to do a web search or check some tutorials, and read [ask]

Comment: This is not very well specified. You don't say what should happen to pixels not equal to 90 - do they remain unchanged? Or become black? Or transparent? When we have made all pixels of 90 into blue are you going to say all pixels of 83 must be yellow and all pixels of 32 need to be purple? Where is this heading?

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load an image from a URL
image = Image.open(requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png', stream=True).raw)

# convert to grayscale
grayscale_image = image.convert('L')
grayscale_array = np.array(grayscale_image)

# get a matrix of with all pixels whith a value above 60
values_above = grayscale_array > 60

# Iterate over all the pixels in the image
for i in range(image.width):
    for j in range(image.height):
        # Check the corresponding value in the boolean matrix - if it is True, set the pixel to blue
        if values_above[i][j]:
            # Change the pixel value to the desired value
            image.putpixel((i, j), (0, 0, 255))

# show image
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```